# I don't know how to interpret this strange $\prod$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, products

I have got a $\prod$ that is exactly as follows:

> $$\prod\limits_{k=0, k \ne k}^n \frac{x-c_k}{c_k-c_k}$$

I am not sure how to interpret this. My guesses are that it equals either $0, or ,1, or ,x$. But perhaps it isn't defined?

Comment: That looks like some poor notational choices have been made there. I'm guessing it's supposed to be more like $$\prod_{i=0, i \neq k}^{n} \frac{x-c_{k}}{c_{i}-c_{k}},$$ or something along those lines....

Comment: @coolpapa I think it is correct notation unfortunately.

Comment: Where did this formula come from?

Comment: @coolpapa University assignment question, small part of some big function.

Comment: Have you got a link? If not, I'd suggest you e-mail your instructor and ask about it.

Comment: Also, $c_k-c_k$ in the denominator, as given, is zero!! And $k \ne k$ is like saying $1 \ne 1$. You can prove a lot from that :)

Comment: It looks like the null-product.

Comment: If the notation is maintained, you could have a lot of fun and not too much work !

Answer (score 6):

Strictly as written the product is $1$. There is no $k$ for which $k \neq k$, [the product is thus empty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_product) (no $k$ fulfills the condition) and thus $1$.

This seems like some sort of "trick question" or a typo (one of the $k$ should be something else), like 
$$\prod\limits_{k=0, \kappa \ne k}^n \frac{x-c_{\kappa}}{c_k-c_{\kappa} }$$ which is sort of common in [Lagrange Interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_interpolation) for instance.

Comment: Using both $\kappa$ and $k$ in a formula is even worse than using both $\alpha$ and $a$

Comment: @Lubin what about $\prod_{\mathscr{k}=0, \mathscr{k}\ne k }\dfrac{x-c_{\scr{k}}}{c_k-c_{\scr{k}}}$?

Comment: Get thee behind me, @Divide1918 !

Answer (score 1):

dividing by zero is typically frowned upon and I see a zero in the denominator of each factor, unless there is a typo?

Comment: I think the limits stop that from mattering. I have for all $k \ne k$, which makes me think it doesn't evaluate.

Comment: Unfortunately at the time, I didn't have the reputation to leave a comment.  Hence the "answer" requesting clarification when at the time there were no answers.